# SQL INNERJOIN with a switch case and if statement in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help:

I have to create a column based on an expression from other columns,

but before that expression hits, there has to be a date check 
if the date is before a specific date- it must do an expression, if the date is after said date, it must do another expression,

THEN: theres a unique column that has the digits 1-10 in it, each number represents a different expression.

the inner join and selecting the rows are fine, its just the switch and if expression that are beating me

basically the statement needs to look like this

```
select column1 if(date<neededDate)
{select case ExpressionColumn
when 1 //do stuff
when 2 // do stuff
else// do nothing
}


select column1 if(date>neededDate)
{select case ExpressionColumn
when 1 //do stuff
when 2 // do stuff
else// do nothing
}
```

i  hope this made sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two case statement nested within another case statement, it can be done like following

```
SELECT CASE WHEN date > neededDate THEN 
                    CASE ExpressionColumn
                        WHEN 1 THEN '1'
                        WHEN 2 THEN '2'
                        ELSE 'null'
                    END
            WHEN date < neededDate THEN 
                    CASE ExpressionColumn
                        WHEN 1 THEN '1'
                        WHEN 2 THEN '2'
                        ELSE 'null'
                    END
            ELSE 'null'
       END
    FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

you have your syntax wrong:

```
select case sign(datediff('s', date, neededDate)) -- precision: second
           when 0 then -- case missing in your spec !
           else
               case ExpressionColumn
                   when 1 then -- case 1
                   when 2 then -- case 2
                   else -- whatever
               end
       end
  from whatever
     ;
```

replace each comment with the appropriate expression over columns.

in your case a searched case expression might be more convenient:

```
select case 
           when (date < neededDate) then
               -- note the difference: instead of 'case x when y then ...' you write 'case when b then ...'
               case ExpressionColumn
                   when 1 then -- case 1
                   when 2 then -- case 2
                   else -- whatever
               end
           when (date > neededDate) then 
               case ExpressionColumn
                   when 1 then -- case 1
                   when 2 then -- case 2
                   else -- whatever
               end
           else -- this is missing from your spec!

       end
  from whatever
     ;
```

Comment: `sgn` is not valid [tag:sql-server] function in your code `case sgn(date - neededDate)` not sure what you were trying to do there.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky transforming the op's spec into a simple case expression. thanks for your hint

Answer (score 1):

You need to check [CASE..WHEN..THEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) in Sql server

Simple CASE expression:

```
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END 
Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```